# How to change labels axis position of dynamic data values that are showing around the chart. I'm using Highcharts here

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I want to change the axis position of data label `6.02%`. How do I change it because this data is dynamic. Here's my code **:**

```
   Highcharts.chart('container' + this.random, {
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: this.graphtitle,
                    align: 'left',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '12px',
                    },
                },
                chart: {
                    height: this.graphheight,
                    width: 500,
                    animation: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000',
                            align: 'left',
                            format: '{point.y} %', // added percentage sign here
                            overflow: 'justify', // prevent labels from being cut off
                            distance: 10, // increase distance between labels
                            x: -40,
                            y: -20,
                            //css
                            style: {
                                fontSize: '10px',
                                textOutline: 0,
                            },
                            connectorWidth: 0,
                        },
                        animation: true,
                        showInLegend: true,
                    },
                },
                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        staggerLines: 2,
                        enabled: true,
                        align: 'left',
                        padding: 0,
                        reserveSpace: true
                    },
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    align: 'right',
                    symbolHeight: 10,
                    symbolRadius: 0,
                    symbolPadding: 1,
                    itemMarginTop: 10,
                    itemMarginBottom: 5,
                    textOutline: 0,
                    itemStyle: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        textOutline: 0,
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    type: 'pie',
                    innerSize: '65%',
                    colors: this.graphcolors,
                    data: this.graphdata,

                },],
           
            });
        },
```

below is the visual of pie chart:

[image]

I was trying this method but it's not working with my code any other method anyone would like to suggest ?

```
chart.series[0].data[1].update({
    dataLabels: {
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        inside: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose graphdata here is dynamic data passed as a props. I came across a similar kind of bottleneck recently.

What I did to resolve this error is following:

You can sort your data ascending or descending using life cycle hooks e.g. getting the highest value element at 0 index or getting the lowest value element at 0 index.

data property of series in high charts expects a object with name and other custom properties to app where graph data has values like

```
['value 1', 1],
['value 2', 2]

         {
                  name: this.graphdata[0][0],
                  y: this.graphdata[0][1],
                  sliced: false,
                  selected: true,
                  dataLabels: {
                    x: -25,
                    y: -15
                  }
                },
               {
               name: this.graphdata[1][0],
               y: this.graphdata[1][1],
               sliced: false,
               selected: true,
               dataLabels: {
                 x: -60,
                y: -25
               }
              },
             this.graphdata[2],
          ],`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you put negative values for [`plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.x`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.x) and [`plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.y`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.y). This is probably not the best strategy if you push data dynamically...

When you use [`setData()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) to update your series, **Highcharts** optimizes labels position automatically.

Here is a simple example:

```js
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      innerSize: '65%',
      dataLabels: {
        format: '{point.y}',
        distance: 10
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }]
});

function getInt() {
  return chance.integer({ min: 1, max: 100 });
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chart.series[0].setData([getInt(), getInt(), getInt()]);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/10.3.3/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chance@1.1.9/chance.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<button type="button">Update</button>
```